# Multiple of a number with nonzero digits

Tags: number-theory

> Determine all positive integers $n$ such that $n$ has a multiple all of its digits are nonzero.

I have worked out the case when $n$ is coprime to $10$.
How do I proceed with cases where $n=2^i$ or $n=5^j$, and $n=a^b\cdot m$ where $a=2$ or $5$?

Comment: I think the question could be made more clear by stating that *all* of the digits has to be non-zero (I think it is the only case if the question is interesting).

Comment: What did you figure out for $n$ relatively prime to $10?$

Comment: @IgorRivin I took the multiple to be $\frac{10^{\phi(9n)}-1}{9}$ which is divisible by $n$ by Euler's theorem ... followed the method from a similar question on SE.